# Can anyone tell me how to display images from database without using gridview or repeater controls?

Tags: asp.net

Please tell, How to display images from local folder in div without using gridview and other displaying controls and please see [This example](http://www.google.co.in/imgres?biw=1366&bih=600&tbm=isch&tbnid=j5Q6CVwN3Lo0KM%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.techalam.com/olx-in-a-great-place-to-buy-sell-stuff-online/&docid=iEIrb6ZbxkzCOM&imgurl=http://www.techalam.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/olx-3.jpg&w=350&h=217&ei=M20kU-O_DM7GrAf8tYGICQ&zoom=1&ved=0COUBEIQcMC8&iact=rc&dur=1752&page=3&start=46&ndsp=19) because I want to display the images like that.

Comment: so.. you want to display them like google does in your link, or like the images in the image from your link? -.-

Comment: http://www.olx.in/cameras-accessories-cat-834....seee this link...how they r displaying their products..!!

Answer (score 0):

well if by displaying controls you mean gridview listview etc. and everything else that is being populated automatically,

you can create a an asp:net panel and in the code behind generate a table and stick it in the panel's innerHTMl and create a row for each of the pictures.

make yourself a function that will generate a row template and create new row for each image, and stick them in that table.

Comment: actually i have two table...
1. tbl_items which contains the following fields
   item_id, items(details)
2. tbl_items_images which contains the images of the related items
   item_id(references tbl_items(item_id))
   image

i want to display only one image for one item...and there r more than one images for each item

Comment: so whats the problem?